# How to make a code more legible

Tags: indentation

I have a very bad formatted code like below.
Is there a way to make this code more legible?

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook           '(lambda ()
             (setq ispell-tex-skip-alists
(list                     (append
                     (car ispell-tex-skip-alists) ;tell ispell to ignore content of this:
                     '(("[^\\]\\$" . "[^\\]\\$")))                    (cadr ispell-tex-skip-alists))) ))
```

Comment: FWIW: No need to quote the `lambda` form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`indent-pp-sexp` with a prefix argument (`C-u C-M-q`) will format the code like this:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      '(lambda
         ()
         (setq ispell-tex-skip-alists
               (list
                (append
                 (car ispell-tex-skip-alists)
                                    ;tell ispell to ignore content of this:
                 '(("[^\\]\\$" . "[^\\]\\$")))
                (cadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))
         ))
```

Comment: `F1 k C-M-q` ...

Comment: Ok thanks,  one should put the cursor just at the beginning of the code before applying `C-u C-M-q`.

Comment: The three things that bother me about that is the `()` on a separate line, the way the comment gets indented, and the fact that the two closing `))` are on a separate line, too.

Answer (score 2):

[lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) can do this with `lispy-tab` command bound to <kbd>i</kbd>.

The result (I added on extra return):

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
            (setq ispell-tex-skip-alists
             (list (append
                    (car ispell-tex-skip-alists) ;tell ispell to ignore content of this:
                    '(("[^\\]\\$" . "[^\\]\\$"))) (cadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))))
```

Comment: Oh, and don't quote lambdas.

Comment: Your extra return actually made the code more legible. I am interested to know if there is any way to automatically do these extra returns or any modifications which make the code more legible (before applying `lispy`).

Comment: If there is, let me know and I'll just add it to `lispy`.

The current approach is semi-acceptable for me, I'm not too eager to
add a bunch of heuristics, at the same time the full approach might be
expensive in terms of implementation-time and run-time.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a problem of extra white space and bad indentation.

1. Select the region
2. Fix white space (replace multiple spaces with single space): `C-M-% \s-+ RET SPACE RET !`
3. Fix indentation (`indent-region`): `C-M-\`

You can even checkout the [`aggressive-indent-mode`](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/aggressive-indent-mode) package (also available on Melpa) and [activate it only for the `emacs-lisp-mode`](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/aggressive-indent-mode#instructions). That will automatically resolve Step 3 above.

Comment: `lispy` will also insert single spaces if they are missing, so take that!:)